# ChainerCV SSD512 MODEL not training

Tags: python-3.x, object-detection, chainercv

I have used SSD300(imagenet pre-trained model) for detection and recognition for two class classification:[Basketball-ChainerCV] (https://github.com/atom2k17/Basketball-ChainerCV/blob/master/basketballproject.py). The training and predictions are good. But when I am using SSD512(imagenet pre-trained model) while training, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
packages/chainer/functions/connection/convolution_2d.py in 
_forward_cudnn(self, x, W, b, y)
226         cuda.cudnn.convolution_forward(
227             x, W, b, y, pad, stride, dilation, self.groups,
228             auto_tune=auto_tune, tensor_core=tensor_core)
229         return y,
230 
cupy/cudnn.pyx in cupy.cudnn.convolution_forward()
cupy/cudnn.pyx in cupy.cudnn._find_algorithm_fwd()
cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.alloc()
cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc()
cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc()
cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool.malloc()
cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool._malloc()
cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory._try_malloc()
OutOfMemoryError: out of memory to allocate 1073741824 bytes (total 
12092240384 bytes)
```

I am using Google Colab GPU environment. Any pointers towards solving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: This is out of memory error, did you try reducing batch size or how about reducing input image size??

Comment: Hi @corochann..I have reduced batch size from 32 to 4.My image size is as it is -320*240..but while training it is displaying loss as nan and validation as 0. Is it still a memory issue?

Comment: No this is other issue. I guess the original question is solved.
When training loss goes nan, please check input contains no nan value and input range is properly scaled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by @corochann this memory issue is solved when trainer.run() was executed taking batch_size as 4 from 32. So taking a smaller batch_size was the solution here.